# C# Formatting a user input to date only

Tags: c#, date, input, format

In my simple program, I need the user to input a date of format dd-mm-yyyy. Then I need to store that date in a text file.

To get the date from the user I use

```
DateTime l_Date = DateTime.ParseExact(Console.ReadLine(), "d-M-yyyy", new CultureInfo("en-CA"));
```

However, it always gets formatted as `2017-07-08 12:00:00 AM`in my text file and I have also tried it in debug and the above line of code does return the date + time. I want only the date.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You could always call .ToShortDateString() when saving the date to your text file. That will at least strip the time component from the DateTime, and you can pass your date format as an argument to that method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `ToShortDateString` method:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna 'Date' part only. You can use `ToShortDateString` as @wablab said.

Also you can use `ToLongDataString` method.

Or use `ToString` with your format, for example: `ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")`.

For more information, follow this link: [MSDN Standard Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)